# How to populate array with values from API using "fetch" in javascript function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to write a function that builds an array where each value of the array is a value pulled from an API using a unique url, once the value is fetched from the API it is pushed into the existing array.

Basically when the function is called I want to populate an array with fetched API data for each stock ticker listed in the List, what i have so far doesnt seem to be working though

```
List: [
                { tick: "AAPL", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "GOOG", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "TSLA", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "J", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "AMZN", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "FB", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "BABA", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "JNJ", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "JPM", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "XOM", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                ],

 totalPortfolio(){
        const arr = List.map((i) => (
            fetch(`${IEX.base_url}/stock/${i.tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(arr => arr.push(arr))
            ));
        console.log(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to await for all of the fetches to finish before you log things.

Reworking your code to async/await functions and adding the required `Promise.all()`:

```
const List = [
  { tick: "AAPL", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "GOOG", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "TSLA", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "J", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "AMZN", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "FB", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "BABA", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "JNJ", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "JPM", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
  { tick: "XOM", datePurch: "01/01/2021" },
];

async function getIntradayPrice(tick) {
  const resp = await fetch(`${IEX.base_url}/stock/${tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`);
  return resp.json();
}

async function totalPortfolio() {
  const respPromises = List.map(({ tick }) => getIntradayPrice(tick));
  const respArrays = await Promise.all(respPromises);
  console.log(respArrays);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting "'getIntradayPrice' is not defined" for when its being called in the map function. Any ideas why? I've added bindings in my react app for the functions and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: If you're getting that error, it means, well, exactly that. The function isn't defined in the scope you're trying to use it in.

Comment: Do you know of any way to get the 'getIntradayPrice' function in scope for the function call in the second function? Nest the function? I've tried a few different options but its not working as written above

Comment: The code as it is exactly above should work just fine (if you have `IEX.base_url` and so on available).

Comment: It looks like the problem was I should've accessed those methods as part of a class (ie this.getIntradayPrice). Your solution now works! thanks